# How to play continuous stream of audio chunks from nodejs server in html5 audio

Tags: node.js, web, audio, socket.io, web-development-server

I am using `ytdl-core` to take a youtube video id and get it's audio url, then I am using nodejs `https` module to stream that audio source through socket.io to all connected clients.
This is the server side code.

```
app.get("/emit", async (req, response) => {
  const yt_id = req.query.yt_id;
  let info = await ytdl.getInfo(yt_id);
  let audioFormats = ytdl.filterFormats(info.formats, "audioonly");
  https.get(audioFormats[0].url, (res) => {
    res.on("data", (data) => {
      io.emit("song", data);
    });
  });
  response.send(audioFormats[0].url);
});
```

Then I am trying to receive these audio chunks on the client side and play them using the html5 audio tag

```
socket.on("song", (data) => {
  const blob = new Blob([data], { type: "audio/wav" });
  songElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
});
```

```
<audio id="song" autoplay controls></audio>
```

But this setup does not seam to work, am I making a mistake or is there any other possible workaround?

PS: all socket connections are perfect and everything is error-less. I just need a way to play these audio chunks in a smooth manner.